# Linux command stdout to stdin?

Tags: linux, command, printf, stdout, stdin

I'm using a GNU/Linux console to set a small bash script. I'm trying to send \n char as input to another program, some like:

```
$printf \\n | program VARS -          #(VARS are valid program modifiers.)
```

but \n char is omitted at executing time so my program could not understand \n as part of the input. The reason about to use the \n char since my program ask for some input which I want to set in blank and my program is waiting for user's input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `printf \\n` can be simplified to `echo`, but both should work. Is your programme really reading from the standard input? Have you tried running it and hitting `Enter`?

Comment: The idea is not hit the Enter, if program needs to be executed more than 300 times, could you imagine hit so many times the enter key? :)

Comment: I understand your idea, I am trying to find a reason why it does not work. Did you get my idea?

Comment: yes, I understand you, I learnt when \n char is in use then use printf instead of echo... printf is more friendable with special chars.

Answer (score 0):

This web page helps me to solve the issue:
https://superuser.com/questions/569432/why-can-i-see-password-prompts-through-redirecting-output

basically (in this case) that program reads input directly from /dev/tty